# Derivatives of the geometric series to prove equality

Tags: sequences-and-series, solution-verification, geometric-series

I have to show that

$(1-p)^{-r} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{k+r-1}{k}p^k$ where $p \in (0,1)$ and $r \in \mathbb{N}_{\geq 1}$.

I got the hint that I have to consider the derivatives of the geometric series. Those would be:

$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} kx^{k-1}, \sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{(n-1)n}{2}x^{n-2}, \dots$

I don't see the pattern to somehow connect this to prove my equality.

**SOLUTION**

We will prove the statement by induction.

*Base case:* $r=1$

$(1-p)^{-1} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} p ^k$ (geometric series), hence base case is true

*Induction step:* Assume $(1-p)^{-r} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{k+r-1}{k}p^k$ for some $r$. We will show that it is true for $r+1$.

$(1-p)^{-(r+1)}= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{k+r-1}{k}p^k \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}p^k$

Using the Cauchy-Product we get:

$=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} p^k\sum_{n=0}^k \binom{n+r-1}{n} $

*Sub-Claim* $\sum_{n=0}^k \binom{n+r-1}{n} = \binom{k+r}{k}$

*Base-Case*: $k=0$ is true

*Induction-step:* Assume $\sum_{n=0}^k \binom{n+r-1}{n} = \binom{k+r}{k}$ for some $k$. We will show it for $k+1$.

$\sum_{n=0}^{k+1}\binom{n+r-1}{n} = \binom{k+1+r-1}{k+1} + \binom{k+r}{k} = \binom{k+1+r}{k+1}$

$\implies $ Sub-claim is true.

We will continue with our first induction:

$=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} p^k\sum_{n=0}^k \binom{n+r-1}{n} $

$=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} p^k \binom{k+r}{k}$

$\implies$ Claim proven

Comment: Another easy approach would be via induction on $r$. Maybe you can try that.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I tried to do it via induction. But couldn't finish it. I've edited my question.

Comment: At the end you need to multiply the series. Do you know how to multiply two series? You should read about Cauchy product of two series. The multiplication is not difficult. Do try out on paper and once successful you may update your question again.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I updated my solution. Thanks for your hint!

Comment: I haven't checked for typos, but otherwise the solution is fine. I am really glad that you solved the problem yourself. +1 and I will add the tag "solution verification".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution using derivatives can also be done via induction. In this approach the key is to know that *a power series can be differentiated term by term in the interior of region of convergence*.

Like your solution we see that the base case for $r=1$ is true. Assume it to be true for $r$ so that $$(1-p)^{-r}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{k+r-1}{k}p^k\tag{1}$$ Differentiating it with respect to $p$ we get $$(-r) (1-p)^{-r-1}(-1)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k\binom{k+r-1}{k}p^{k-1}$$ Note that the first term for $k=0$ in right side of equation $(1)$ is a constant $1$ so on differentiation this becomes $0$ and I have removed it altogether so that the summation index now starts from $k=1$. Next I shift the summation index $k$ by $1$ so that it again starts from $0$ and thus the above equation is written as $$r(1-p)^{-(r+1)}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (k+1)\binom{k+r}{k+1}p^k$$ or $$(1-p)^{-(r+1)}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{k+1}{r}\binom{k+r}{k+1}p^k\tag{2}$$ Next observe that $$\frac{k+1}{r}\binom{k+r}{k+1}=\frac{k+1}{r} \frac{(k+r)!}{(k+1)!(r-1)!}=\frac{(k+r)!}{k!r!}=\binom{k+r}{k}$$ And therefore equation $(2)$ can be rewritten as $$(1-p)^{-(r+1)}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{k+r} {k} p^k\tag{3}$$ which shows that the formula holds for $r+1$ also. The proof is now complete by induction.

You should observe that this approach requires similar amount of work as compared to the solution given in question.

Comment: Thank you for the feel good success story that is this post, and my +1  is for your help to the OP and the answer! May we have many more success stories to report.

Comment: Thank you very much! :)